# How do I wait for turnstile.execute to finish?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloudflare, cloudflare-turnstile

I am trying to use Cloudflare's turnstile documented [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/turnstile/get-started/client-side-rendering/) with the `execution` option. I am calling `turnstile.execute` in an async function called after a button press, but the function doesn't seem to be wait for the challenge to finish before continuing. Is there a way I can `await` or something similar on `turnstile.execute` so that I am able to use the token in the `callback` later on in the function?

Comment: This is a very good question, there is no documentation for this. I already tried .then but it's not available.